# How to get financial quarters date by current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

The quarters described as below:

```
APRIL - JUNE   - Q1
JULY  - SEPT   - Q2
OCT   - DEC    - Q3
JAN   - MARCH  - Q4
```

For ex:

```
Date = '2018-12-24'  -- Where this date is under third quarter
```

So Expected should be [Get all quarter < current date's quarter]

```
---------------------------
Quarters
---------------------------
01 Jul 2018 - 30 Sep 2018
01 Apr 2018 - 30 Jun 2018
---------------------------
```

If the

```
Date = '2019-01-24' -- Where this date is under fourth quarter
```

Expected result:

```
---------------------------
Quarters
---------------------------
01 Oct 2018 - 30 Dec 2018
01 Jul 2018 - 30 Sep 2018
01 Apr 2018 - 30 Jun 2018
---------------------------
```

The query that I have tried:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2019-01-24 18:15:59.517' 
DECLARE @FirstDayOfQuarter DATETIME 
DECLARE @LastDayOfQuarter DATETIME 

SET @FirstDayOfQuarter = (SELECT Dateadd(qq, Datediff(qq, 0, @dt) - 1, 0)) 
SET @LastDayOfQuarter = (SELECT Dateadd(dd, -1, Dateadd(qq, Datediff(qq, 0, @dt) 
                                                , 0))) 

DECLARE @year INT 

SET @year = Datepart(year, @dt) 

DECLARE @currQ NVARCHAR(max) 

SET @currQ = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @FirstDayOfQuarter, 106) 
                     + Space(1) + '-' + Space(1) 
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @LastDayOfQuarter, 106)) 

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), Dateadd(m, 3*number, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR( 
       5), 
       @year)+'-1-1')), 106) 
       + Space(1) + '-' + Space(1) 
       + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), Dateadd(d, -1, Dateadd(m, 3*number+3, CONVERT( 
       DATE, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @year)+'-1-1'))), 106) AS Quarter, 
       number, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @dt BETWEEN Dateadd(m, 3 * number, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5 
                                                               ), 
                                                               @year) + 
                                                               '-1-1')) AND 
                                 Dateadd(d, -1, Dateadd(m, 3 * number + 3, 
                                                CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5) 
                                                              , 
                          @year 
                          ) + '-1-1'))) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END                                        AS isCurrentQuarter 
INTO   #allquarters 
FROM   master..spt_values 
WHERE  type = 'p' 
       AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 4 

SELECT TOP 1 number, 
             CASE 
               WHEN @dt BETWEEN Dateadd(m, 3 * number, 
                                CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), 
                                              @year) + 
                                              '-1-1')) AND 
                                       Dateadd(d, -1, Dateadd(m, 3 * number + 3, 
                                                      CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT( 
                                                      VARCHAR(5), 
                                @year 
                                ) + '-1-1'))) THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END AS isCurrentQuarter 
INTO   #currentquarter 
FROM   master..spt_values 
WHERE  type = 'p' 
       AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 4 
ORDER  BY iscurrentquarter DESC, 
          number ASC 

SELECT quarter 
FROM   #allquarters 
WHERE  number < (SELECT number 
                 FROM   #currentquarter) 
ORDER  BY number DESC 

DROP TABLE #allquarters 

DROP TABLE #currentquarter
```

It is working for `GETDATE()` but when I put the date as `2019-01-24 18:15:59.517` then it gives me empty result

**EDIT:**

If the

```
Date = '2019-05-24' -- Where this date is under first quarter of next year
```

Expected result:

```
---------------------------
Quarters
---------------------------
01 Jan 2019 - 30 March 2019
01 Oct 2018 - 30 Dec 2018
01 Jul 2018 - 30 Sep 2018
01 Apr 2018 - 30 Jun 2018
---------------------------
```

If the

```
Date = '2018-05-24' -- Where this date is under the first quarter of current year
```

Expected result:

```
---------------------------
Quarters
---------------------------
01 Jan 2018 - 30 March 2018
01 Oct 2017 - 30 Dec 2017
01 Jul 2017 - 30 Sep 2017
01 Apr 2017 - 30 Jun 2017
---------------------------
```

Comment: Side note: [Please don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially on SQL Server.  You'll find it much easier to query ranges that have an exclusive upper bound, among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula `(n + 5) % 12 + 3` to convert month numbers 1, 2, ..., 12 to 9, 10, ..., 14, 3, ..., 8 which is the number of months you need to subtract from a given date. In SQL Server 2008 you would translate it as:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, inputdate) - ((MONTH(inputdate) + 5) % 12 + 3), 0)
```

The converts `2018-04-xx` to `2017-04-01` and `2018-07-xx` to `2018-04-01`. Adding 3, 6 and 9 months is trivial.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b378a404cd3103aa1d3f12776f46d3db)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does what you want:

```
with dte as (
      select cast('2019-07-24' as date) as dte
     )
select dte,
       (convert(varchar(255), dateadd(month, v.n, datefromparts(year(dte), ((month(dte) - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1, 1)), 106) + ' - ' +
        convert(varchar(255), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, v.n + 3, datefromparts(year(dte), ((month(dte) - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1, 1))), 106)
      ) as string 
from dte cross apply
     (values (0), (-3), (-6), (-9)) v(n)
where month(dte) < 4 or month(dte) >= 13 + v.n
order by v.n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9291ed1ce003012b49fdcfa4f9deb3e3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: When I enter --> `2019-01-01` which is first JAN gives me error --> `Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale . . . I had tested it for many dates, but I must've made a change that broke it.  In any case, the db<>fiddle link tests every month.

Comment: Thanks! Will try with other date's also